# textarea if is not working

Tags: php, html

i don't find the problem:
When I don't type anything in the textarea (name="bs") it is not showing me the error message. 
When I change the textarea into an input field it works.

How can I make this also working for the textarea?

```
   <form action="feedback.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="email"><br>
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>

   <textarea name="bs" cols="50" rows="5">
   </textarea><br>

   <input type="submit" value="absenden" name="b"><br>
     </form> 

   <?php
   if (isset($_POST["b"])) {
   echo "1";
   $fehler = false;
   $fehlertext = '';

   if (empty($_POST["name"])){
   $fehler = true;
   $fehlertext .= 'Der Name fehlt<br>';
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
   $fehler = true;
   $fehlertext .= 'Die email  adresse fehlt';
   }         

  if (empty($_POST["bs"])) {
  $fehler = true;              
  $fehlertext   .= 'Das kommentar feld muss ausgefüllt werden!<br>';
  }  
      if ($fehler) {
   echo "$fehlertext";
 }else{

   $mailbody = $_POST['name'] . " schrieb\n\n<br><br>";
   $mailbody .= $_POST['bs'];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   $mailbody = stripslashes($mailbody);
   $email =  $_POST['email'];
  if (@mail("edin2007@outlook.de","feedback",$mailbody,
   "From: $email"))  {
   echo "danke johann hanke";
   }else{
   echo "leider gab es einen sendefehler<br><br>";
  } 
  }
  }
   ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you echo the length of the textarea's input? Ex `echo strlen($_POST["bs"]);`. I'm wondering if there's white space that should be trimmed because of how you have your HTML formatted.

Comment: It is because you have the close tag for the textarea on the next line so you have blank space. Either move the close tag up immediately behind the open tag, or `trim()` as suggested by @j08691

Comment: great thank you!!! I deleted the space and it works!!! THANK YOU!